# EXCEL DEBUG Formula " =

Tags: excel, debugging

I am trying to figure out how to use the syntax in both of the cases listed below. There is a cell with the equation ='1a'!L21 that asks me to open a file, and I am not sure why. When I select the same excel file and sheet I get #REF! Error.

I am trying to use that to then use an `If` statement as follows:

```
=IF((E8-'1a'!E8)>0,E8-'1a'!E8,0)
```

Comment: @pnuts - It is perhaps worth posting as answer, so it is removed from the list "without answer". In the end, it is likely **the** answer.

Comment: @pnuts - You are right. PS: I already flagged for migration to SU.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer:

The first formula is looking for the contents of L21 in `Sheet 1a` - this sheet does not exist in the relevant workbook, so Excel is offering you the opportunity to search for that sheet in another workbook.

Comment: Hi, Don't take me in the wrong sense, but is [*For the sake of an answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1505120+For+the+sake+of+an+answer%3A+) really necessary? Regards.

Comment: I did want to ask on meta, However not many use the phrase. It has been used [only 11 other times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22For+the+sake+of+an+answer%22). As it was too focused only on one user, I felt it was better to speak to you instead of asking the community. In anycase, I'll do a bit more research and definitely ask a question on meta. Thanks.